# PHP/MYSQL if else

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am creating a baseball website and I am learning php as I go. I have hit a snag with something I am trying to do; here is what my current code shows:

[image: MLB Scoreboard]

here is my code:
[image]

When I load my files that update the scores, if the game hasn't started the scores are NULL. Is there a code to change it to 0 without having to change it in my database. Any info will be helpful

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not as an image. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to post formatted code.

Comment: You can use `SELECT IFNULL(score, 0) AS score` to turn null scores into `0`.

Comment: You could also change the table schema to use `DEFAULT 0` for the score columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you can use the IFNULL(expr1, 0) function, but you will need to list your columns explicitly instead of using select *. So it would be roughly:

```
select 
  game_date, 
  game_time, 
  ..., 
  IFNULL(AWAY_SCORE, 0), 
  IFNULL(HOME_SCORE, 0) 
FROM scoreboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, by way of PHP. It could also be done in the database query

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc(){
    $ascore = $row['score'];
    $hscore= $row['score'];
    if($ascore == ""){
       $ascore = 0;
    if($hscore== ""){
       $hscore = 0;
    }

    REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
   }
}
```